# Integrate syncfusion chart with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, charts, bar-chart, syncfusion

I am using syncfusion for my application to display chart and I have used [this](https://help.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/chart/getting-started#initialize-chart) documentation to create demo page.

Page comes without any error but chart is not displayed on the page.

As I have done inspect there is a code available but not display on page.

I have attached the screen shot please look into that.

[image]

Code:

Controller side:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //// Create dataSource to chart
            List<ChartData> data = new List<ChartData>();
            data.Add(new ChartData("Jan", 35));
            data.Add(new ChartData("Feb", 28));
            data.Add(new ChartData("Mar", 34));
            data.Add(new ChartData("Apr", 32));
            data.Add(new ChartData("May", 40));
            data.Add(new ChartData("Jun", 32));
            data.Add(new ChartData("Jul", 35));
            data.Add(new ChartData("Aug", 55));
            data.Add(new ChartData("Sep", 38));
            data.Add(new ChartData("Oct", 30));
            data.Add(new ChartData("Nov", 25));
            data.Add(new ChartData("Dec", 32));
            ///...
            ViewBag.ChartData = data;
            return View();
        }
     }          

    public class ChartData {
        public string Month;
        public double Sales;
        public ChartData(string month, double sales)
        {
            this.Month = month;
            this.Sales = sales;
        }
    }
```

CSHTML:

```
@using Syncfusion.JavaScript.DataVisualization

<!--  jquery script  -->
    <script src="http://cdn.syncfusion.com/js/assets/external/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>    

    <!-- Essential JS UI widget -->
    <script src="http://cdn.syncfusion.com/13.1.0.21/js/web/ej.web.all.min.js"></script>

    <!--Add Syncfusion Script Manager -->
    @Html.EJ().ScriptManager()

 <div>

               @(Html.EJ().Chart("chartContainer")
                    .Series(sr =>
                         { 
                            //Change series type
                            sr.Type(SeriesType.Line).Add();                  
                         })
               )
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have analyzed the query with the attached screenshot. We suspect that, you have set true to **UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled**, but haven’t referred ej.unobtrusive.min.js file. So we recommend to refer **ej.unobtrusive.min.js** file. Kindly find the code snippet below.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/ej/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ej/ej.web.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ej/ej.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

For reference we have attached the sample. Kindly find the
[Sample Link](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/169425/ze/unobtrusive_chart1697931970)

Unobtrusive JavaScript support will create the components with basic level HTML tag-like structure in order to reduce the weightage of the page. For more information on Unobtrusive, kindly follow the below link

[Help document](https://help.syncfusion.com/js/unobtrusive-support)

Thanks,
Dharani.

Comment: Thanks for the response D. Dharanidharan but I have already solve above issue. Can you please solve my [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220815/use-hidden-field-in-syncfusion-column-chart-series) problem.